# Solve for real x: $(\sqrt[5]{x+2}-\sqrt[5]{2x+1}-\sqrt[5]{4x+7})^5=3x+8$ (possible typo on the original question)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Source: [School Science and Mathematics Journal 2023 February. Problem 5723](https://www.ssma.org/assets/docs/ProblemSolutionsSection/2023-Problem-Solutions/2023-02-Problems-Solutions-SSMJ-%23%23%23%205721-5726.pdf).

My ideas were that:

Obviously the entire expression to the power of 5 would make it messy , so I wrote it as: $(\sqrt[5]{x+2}-\sqrt[5]{2x+1}-\sqrt[5]{4x+7})=\sqrt[5]{3x+8}\\$

edit 1: The closed form  for the solution as pointed out by @Ajay would be something like  $-\sqrt{3}$ if that helps. Wolfram suggests :$x ≈ -1.69436783548923 \dots$. I'm also trying to find the actual closed form for this.

edit 2:Another approximate form for the root is $1-\sqrt[5]{142} \approx -1.694372$ as pointed out by @Robert Z.

Now taking $\sqrt[5]{4x+7}$ to the other side:
$\sqrt[5]{x+2}-\sqrt[5]{2x+1}=\sqrt[5]{3x+8}+\sqrt[5]{4x+7}\\$

I could see that $(2x+1)-(x+2) = (4x+7)-(3x+8)$.
However I'm not able to exploit this in any manner, due to $\sqrt[5]{}$.

I was looking at expressions like :$a^5 - b^5=(a – b)(a^4 + a^3b + a^2b^2 + ab^3 + b^4)$. But this has been of no use either.

Graphing it, it does spit out a solution. So i couldn't really use inequalities, to prove that no solutions exist.
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145057/discussion-on-question-by-q123lsab-solve-for-real-x-sqrt5x2-sqrt52x); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @XanderHenderson "*Comments have been moved to chat*" $\;-\;$ Why? It's not like there were that many comments, anyway, and removing them deprives future readers from relevant insight into the question, and into the answers below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possible typo: the equation could be
$$(\sqrt[5]{x+2}\color{red}{\large+}\sqrt[5]{2x+1}-\sqrt[5]{4x+7})^5=3x+8$$
which is equivalent to
$$f(x):=\sqrt[5]{2x+1}-\sqrt[5]{4x+7}=\sqrt[5]{3x+8}-\sqrt[5]{x+2}:=g(x).$$
Note that $f(x)\geq 0$ if and only if $2x+1\geq 4x-7$, that is for $x\leq -3$.
On the other hand, $g(x)\geq 0$ if and only if $3x+8\geq x+2$, that is for $x\geq -3$.
Hence the equality $f(x)=g(x)$ holds only for $x=-3$.

As regards the variant proposed by Claude Leibovici,
$$(\sqrt[5]{x+2}-\sqrt[5]{2x+1}\color{red}{\large+}\sqrt[5]{4x+7})^5=3x+8.$$
In this case the real solutions are three: $1$, $-3$, and $-\frac{9}{5}$.
Basically they follow by pairing the radicands:
$$1)\, \begin{cases}
x+2=2x+1\\
4x+7=3x+8
\end{cases};\quad 2)\, \begin{cases}x+2=3x+8\\4x+7=2x+1
\end{cases};\quad 3)\,\begin{cases}x+2=-4x-7\\3x+8=-2x-1
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: I agree with this solution. By far this is the most satisfactory solution to the corrected algebra problem .

Comment: (+1) but the question seems correct according to the linked problem set

Comment: @DS I sent an email to the proposers (in the linked problem set). Let's wait for their reply...

Comment: ok. You might also want to add that $f(x) <0$ iff $x>-3$ and $g(x)<0$ iff $x<-3$

Comment: @DS $f(x) <0$ on the complement of the set where $f(x) \geq 0$

Comment: this seems alright. As unfortunately , a closed form could not be found for the original equation. I'll mark this as correct, and wait for confirmation. Thank you!

Comment: @q123LsaB The solution of the original equation is the unique real root of a [polynomial of degree $25$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=groebnerbasis%5B%7Bu-v-w-t%2Cu%5E5-x-2%2Cv%5E5-2x-1%2Cw%5E5-4x-7%2Ct%5E5-3x-8%7D%2C%7Bx%7D%2C%7Bu%2Cv%2Cw%2Ct%7D%5D) not solvable in radicals. It was most certainly a typo.

Comment: @dxiv yes but what if some substitution is able to convert it into something very simple? although it is very unlikely. Yes, it must be a typo.

Comment: @q123LsaB Not just unlikely, but provable impossible using only radicals. Beyond that, I guess it depends on what you would call "*very simple*".

Comment: Making $x=-9/5$ leads me to $lhs-rhs=-2.61473+0.00643209\, i$ (!!) for the original equation

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Use the real function $t\to\sqrt[5]{t}$: $x=-9/5$ yields $lhs=(\sqrt[5]{1/5}-\sqrt[5]{-13/5}+\sqrt[5]{-1/5})^5$, $rhs=13/5$ which holds.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici This desmos graph spits out $x=-9/5$ as a solution too : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x4i2z1mjns

Comment: @q123LsaB Professor Bencze confirmed the presence of a typo, but he did not specify the correct equation

Comment: @RobertZ Okay! Ill update it once the solutions are out!

Comment: @ RobertZ The pairing idea is great! 1+

Answer (score 8):

If the problem is $$(\sqrt[5]{x+2}-\sqrt[5]{2x+1}\color{red}{\large+}\sqrt[5]{4x+7})^5=3x+8$$

the two real solutions are $x=1$ and $x=-3$.

Comment: The real solutions in this case are THREE. There is also $-9/5$. See my edit.

Comment: The main idea to get the third solution is to take the branch of the power function for $x \gt 0$ such  that $\sqrt[5]{-x}=-x$

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. Thanks for the comment. It is the usual problem of $\sqrt[3]x$

Answer (score 4):

Let us systematically follow the pairing strategy of Robert Z, described in his solution in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4671282/198592 for different variants of the signs in the equation.

We assume a branch of the power function such that

$$\sqrt[5]{-x}=-\sqrt[5]{x}\tag{1}$$

Define the set of equations of interest as

$$q(a,b) := \left(\sqrt[5]{x+2}+a \sqrt[5]{2 x+1}+b \sqrt[5]{4 x+7}\right)^5=3 x+8\tag{2}$$

Then we have

for $q(+1,+1)$ we find one solution $x=+1$

1. Pairing 1 with 2 to cancel: $x+2 = -2x-1$ -> $x=1$, and 3 with rhs $4x+7=3x+8$ -> $x=1$
   Consistent, hence one solution found: $x=1$
2. Pairing 2 with 3 to cancel: $2x+1=-4x-7$ -> $x=-1$
   and 1 with rhs to be equal: $x+2=3x+8$ -> $x=-3$.
   Inconsistent, hence no solution found.
3. Pairing 1 with 3 to cancel: $x+2=-4x-7$ -> $x=-9/5$
   and 2 with rhs to be equal: $2x+1=3x+8$ -> $x=-7$.
   Inconsistent, hence no solution found.

for $q(+1,-1)$ we find one solution: $x=-3$

1. Pairing 1 with 2 to cancel: $x+2 = -2x-1$ -> $x=-1$, and 3 with rhs $4x+7=-3x-8$ -> $x=-15/7$
   Inconsistent, hence no solution found.
2. Pairing 2 with 3 to cancel: $2x+1=4x+7$ -> $x=-3$
   and 1 with rhs to be equal: $x+2=3x+8$ -> $x=-3$.
   Consistent. Hence one solution found: $x=-3$
3. Pairing 1 with 3 to cancel: $x+2=4x+7$ -> $x=-5/3$
   and 2 with rhs to be equal: $2x+1=3x+8$ -> $x=-7$.
   Inconsistent, hence no solution found.

for $q(-1,-1)$ we find no solutions

1. Pairing 1 with 2 to cancel: $x+2 = 2x+1$ -> $x=1$, and 3 with rhs $4x+7=-3x-8$ -> $x=-15/7 $
   Inconsitent, hence no solution found
2. Pairing 2 with 3 to cancel: $2x+1=-4x-7$ -> $x=-4/3$
   and 1 with rhs to be equal: $x+2=3x+8$ -> $x=-3$.
   Inconsistent, hence no solution found
3. Pairing 1 with 3 to cancel: $x+2=4x+7$ -> $x=-5/3$
   and 2 with rhs to be equal: $2x+1=-3x-8$ -> $x=-7/5$.
   Inconsistent, hence no solution found.

for $q(-1,+1)$ (Claude Leibovici, Robert Z) we find three solutions $x=1,-3,-9/5$

1. Pairing 1 with 2 to cancel: $x+2 = 2x+1$ -> $x=1$, and 3 with rhs $4x+7=3x+8$ -> $x=1 $
   Consistent, hence one solution found: $x=1$
2. Pairing 2 with 3 to cancel: $2x+1=4x+7$ -> $x=-3$
   and 1 with rhs to be equal: $x+2=3x+8$ -> $x=-3$.
   Inconsistent, hence one solution found: $x=-3$
3. Pairing 1 with 3 to cancel: $x+2=-4x-7$ -> $x=-9/5$
   and 2 with rhs to be equal: $2x+1=-3x-8$ -> $x=-9/5$.
   Consistent, hence one solution found: $x=-9/5$

Hence it is most probably $q(-1,1)$ which was meant in the OP.

**Discussion**

1. Interestingly, the equation with a general power $p$,

$$q(p, a,b) := \left(\sqrt[p]{x+2}+a \sqrt[p]{2 x+1}+b \sqrt[p]{4 x+7}\right)^p=3 x+8\tag{3}$$

has for any odd $p \ge 3$ and $(a,b) = (-1,+1)$ the same three solutions $x=+1, -3, -9/5$ as for the case of the OP, $p=5$.

2. Three-dimensional graph in the complex range exhibits the three solutions on the real x-axis one of which ($x=-9/5$) is missing in a purely real plot

[image]